# How to justify text in TextView like Kindle (Android)

Tags: android, textview, kindle, justify

I'm looking for a way to justify text like Kindle app does on Android.
I've read that Android doesen't support full justification but, if it is so, how Kindle does implement it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean to center text inside the TextView?

Comment: No, i mean to make all space in lines occupied like newspaper columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've read that Android doesen't support full justification

If you read more closely, you would have noticed that the discussion of full justification tends to be centered around `TextView`.

> how Kindle does implement it?

Not by `TextView`. They either are using `WebView` or their own content rendering engine. AFAIK, `WebView` supports [CSS `text-align` and `text-justify`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp).